# How to change the default database name in a DbContext?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have created the project the code for make Db set is

```
public class ImpalDBContext : DbContext
{
public DbSet<DataDisplay> ImpalaDb { get; set; }
}
```

And when Entity Framework create the database name =" ImpalaPortal.Models.ImpalDBContext"

how to make change the default Databse name in mvc 4 I want to make short name in one word

Comment: You are confusing EntityFramework with ASP.NET MVC...

Answer (score 1):

There's a `DbContext` [constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) that receives the name of the connection string as a parameter, so you can give whatever name you like, as long as there's a connection string with that name in the Web.Config file.

You probably want to modify your `ImpalDBContext` to have this constructor

```
public class ImpalDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ImpalDBContext(string connectionStringName):base(connectionStringName) { }
    public DbSet<DataDisplay> ImpalaDb { get; set; }
}
```

Or, you could just change the name of the default connection string like this:

```
public class ImpalDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ImpalDBContext():base("YourConnectionStringName") { }
    public DbSet<DataDisplay> ImpalaDb { get; set; }
}
```

If I'm not wrong, the later will even make the EntityFramework to change the name of the generated database.

Comment: Impreseive Thank you :)

Comment: @BeginerProgramer, if you don't mind, please accept my answer.